# Supressing AJAX/hash behavior for certain links only in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, hashbang

I found some old answers for this, but they do not seem no longer valid for jQuery Mobile.

I want to disable AJAX/hashbang behavior certain links only. 
I have found out I can disable it globally:

```
/**
 * Supress some jQuery Mobile default behavior
 */
$(window.document).bind("mobileinit", function() {


    // https://github.com/mobilizejs/mobilize.js/blob/master/js/mobilize.onjq.js#L51
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

});
```

... but I'd like to disable it for certain  classes only, so that my custom click() handlers are not screwed up. Looks like return true or e.preventDefault() in click() do not help this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a link-by-link basis the two main ways of suppressing the default Ajax navigation are to either set a `rel=external` attribute, or set any kind of `target` attribute.

Given that, you could either update the mark-up of the relevant links, or better, assign the attribute you choose dynamically when your pages are loading.

Answer (score 1):

At some point `data-ajax="false"` was introduced.